# bootstrap_barrio subtheme breaks ckeditor's media insert in custom block

Tags: blocks, media, layout-builder

I'm facing this problem (seems to be producible) in a contrib theme that breaks the ckeditor media insert button on custom blocks in the layout builder of individual nodes...
The javascript error says it's typically caused by the theme neglecting to include proper html attributes for that entity type, but the theme's block.html.twig is identical to that template in Bartik.  This is a custom subtheme of bootstrap_barrio created with the shell script provided by bootstrap_sass (Barrio highly recommends subtheming that way).  Error has been repeated on new D8 and D9 installations, and the full message on page load is:

```
Uncaught Error: Quick Edit could not associate the rendered entity field markup (with [data-quickedit-field-id="block_content/1/body/en/full"]) with the corresponding rendered entity markup: no parent DOM node found with [data-quickedit-entity-id="block_content/1"]. This is typically caused by the theme's template for this entity type forgetting to print the attributes.
```

and while editing a block in the layout builder, clicking ckeditor's media insert button results in the following error (and the media dialog never opens, the "Loading..." message appears but nothing loads):

```
Object { message: "\nAn AJAX HTTP error occurred.\nHTTP Result Code: 500\nDebugging information follows.\nPath: /media-library?media_library_opener_id=media_library.opener.editor&media_library_allowed_types%5B0%5D=image&media_library_selected_type=image&media_library_remaining=1&media_library_opener_parameters%5Bfilter_format_id%5D=basic_html&hash=Ul_KDXiNyg8Mw95OeXpaIZUYieACO4FlRCUQkle_TCs\nStatusText: Internal Server Error\nResponseText: The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.", name: "AjaxError", stack: "@https://atn.ddev.site/core/misc/ajax.js?v=8.9.3:100:32\n@https://atn.ddev.site/core/misc/ajax.js?v=8.9.3:643:3\n" }
```

I was very excited about the bootstrap_barrio's subtheme with sass, gulp, browsersync all configured with bootstrap, but maybe I should switch to radix?  I'd much prefer to solve this error though, if anyone has any insight?  I don't know where to begin with javascript debugging :(

Comment: If it's a reproducible issue caused by a contrib module, this should be reported in the module's issue queue, not asked as a question here.  Bugs with contrib modules are off topic for this site.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because if it's a reproducible issue caused by a contrib module, this should be reported in the module's issue queue, not asked as a question here. Bugs with contrib modules are off topic for this site.